# Accessing an array of $_POSTed variables in a PHP foreach loop 

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, indexing

I'm looking to iterate through some $_POSTed variables from an HTML form. Unfortunately, I can't figure out to access each "row" to do stuff to it.

```
$_POST['names'] = array('alan', 'bob', 'carl', 'dan', 'ed');
$_POST['emails'] = array('0@.com', '1@com', '2.com', '3.com', '4.com');
$data=$_POST;

foreach($data as $index=>$row){
  doSomethingNames($row[$index]); //in reality, this would be a more complicated function that needs to access each row's variables, same for printEmails()
  doSomethingEmails($row[$index]); 
}

function doSomethingNames($row){
   print_r($row['names']);// should print alan-bob-carl-dan-ed
}

function doSomethingEmails($row){
   print_r($row['emails']); //should print 0.com-1.com-2.com-3.com-4.com
}
```

Running this code currently prints nothing. Any help someone might provide to help me access each rows' data would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why is this question downvoted? I'm happy to make it better.

Comment: I guess it's not clear to readers from the code what you're interested in. You may need to help them understand with some plain explanation. Your question looks fine as it is though so I've reopened it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is use another structure of array:

```
<?php
    $data['names'] = array('0aa', '1bb', '2cc', '3dd', '4ee');
    $data['emails'] = array('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE');

    $united_data = array();
    $count = count( $data['names'] );

    for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
    {
        array_push( $united_data, 
            array( 'name' => $data['names'][$i], 'email' => $data['emails'][$i] )
        );
    }

    foreach( $united_data as $key => $val ){
        printNames( $united_data[$key] );
        printEmails( $united_data[$key] );

    }

    function printNames( $row ){
        echo 'name: ' . $row['name'] . ', ';
    }

    function printEmails( $row ){
        echo 'email: ' . $row['email'] . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: can you explain how i convert the arrays I gave into the one you made ?

Comment: How you receive these arrays?

Comment: $_POST['names'] and $_POST['emails'] from an HTML form.

Comment: Use array_combine($_POST['names'], $_POST['emails']);

Comment: And that's because...? C'mon, try to search and understand instead of just ask and expect it's done by someone else.

Comment: @oso96_2000 i've been actively searching for over an hour now and have already tested array_combine(). I responded so tersely to be efficient and indicate that we move on to the next thing rather than suggest I want someone else to do the work for me. Get your facts right.

Comment: One of many variants of merging arrays into one `$united_array`. Check my code again. This is example only, don't use it in production.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished like this:

```
$data['names'] = array('0aa', '1bb', '2cc', '3dd', '4ee');
$data['emails'] = array('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE');

foreach($data as $index => $row){
  echo $index . ': ' . implode('-', $row);
}
```

This will print the name of the index and use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to get a string of the elements.

New example:

```
$data['names'] = array('0aa', '1bb', '2cc', '3dd', '4ee');
$data['emails'] = array('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['names']); $i++) {
  echo $data['names'][$i] . ': ' . $data['emails'][$i] . '<br />';
}
```

**This only works when the number of elements of both arrays is the same.**

Comment: i need to access each member of both arrays, the implode() is irrelevant

Comment: Then you need to understand how arrays work. When using numeric indexes, they start from 0, so you can access them like: $data['names'][1] (would be 1bb) and $data['emails][1] (BB)

Comment: yeah i don't understand arrays that well. Your code is getting me closer. Can you incorporate those function calls in your answer to print either names/emails?

Comment: What would you like to accomplish? What do you want to print? I'll assume that you want to print $name : $email.

Comment: yes I just need to understand how to set up each row's name and email such that I can feed them into the `printName()/printEmails()` function calls and access them from there.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope that helps you to understand how to do that :)

Comment: can you just include the function calls in your answer and do the `echo` from within them?

Comment: @tim, I edited my answer, as per your discussion here. take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you're trying to accomplish what you wan't is definitely not a valid way. Use  PHP's array function [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
function printNames($row) {
  echo implode("-", $row['names']);
}
```

What this does is iterate through every member of the array and return a string with the iterated values joined separated by the "glue" (the minus sign in this case). Keep in mind that the glue is optional, doing the following is also valid (although discouraged, better to use an empty string for the glue instead).

```
function printNames($row) {
  echo implode($row['names']);
}
```

Comment: i don't care about the "glue". I only used that for readability.

Comment: You have a problem with your `for..each` also, check another answer.

Comment: can you explain with code what the problem with my foreach loop is?

Comment: The thing about foreach loops is that they don't log the variable that you're running through. Instead of saying `printNames($row[$index]);`, try saying `printNames($data[$index]);` and then removing `['names']` from the implode, or `printNames($data);`

Answer (score 0):

just use `implode()`. it concatenates the values in a array with the `-`.

```
 function printNames($row){     
 print_r(implode('-',$row)); // should print 0aa-1bb-2cc-3dd-4ee
}

function printEmails($row){
 print_r(implode('-', $row)); //should print AA-BB-CC-DD-EE
}
```

**Edit:**

```
 foreach($data as $index => $row){
  foreach($row as $k =>$v) {
  if($k === 'names')
   printNames($v);
  else 
    printEmails($v);
 }
}

 function printNames($elem){
   print_r($elem); echo '-';// should print 0aa-1bb-2cc-3dd-4ee
 }

function printEmails($element){
   print_r($elem); echo'-'; //should print AA-BB-CC-DD-EE
}
```